# Are the blocks in the Bloqs Add-On repeatable?

Tags: add-on, blocks

I am asking a very basic question which I could not with 100 % certainty answer by browsing both the old and new owner's web site and documentation of Bloqs (EE3)/Blocks (EE2) or by searching on EE Aswers. Any example I could find was a demonstration how to use the Bloqs once. I'm considering a purchase and contacting the current owner was without any response so far.

**Can I use the predefined Blocks more than once per entry?**

as in the following example ordering:

```
caption

quote

text-field

photoslide

text-field

photo-slide

text-field
```

*Optional question: how would that look like in template code?
Would it be enough to define the Bocks layout in template once and it would figure the order of repeated blocks itself or do have to hardcode an order myself?*

I know I can probably make a grid and use Bloqs as field type and get it to do what I want, but it could be much simpler if the bloqs would be repeatable.

Thanks to anybody who can point me into the right direction (favorably somebody who uses Bloqs in an EE3 instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm using bloqs. First time, but it seems to do whatever i like it to. So repeatable content blocks works. It takes the order you give it in the entry screen. The setup in the templates is pretty easy too. I use a tag and a snippet in the templates like this:

```
{pages_page_builder}
{sn_page_builder}
{pages_page_builder}
```

And my (very basic) snippet looks like this:

```
{gecentreerde_titel}
                    {if titel}
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2>{titel}</h2>
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                 {/gecentreerde_titel}
                 {brede_tekst}
                    {if titel}
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2>{titel}</h2>
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    {if tekst}
                        <div class="row">
                            {tekst} {if link}
                                        <a href="{link}" title="">Lees verder</a>
                                    {/if}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                 {/brede_tekst}
                 {2_blokken_met_tekst_en_achtergrondafbeelding}
                    <div>
                    {if blok_1_afbeelding}
                        {blok_1_afbeelding}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_1_kop}
                        {blok_1_kop}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_1_tekst}
                        {blok_1_tekst}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_1_link}
                        {blok_1_link}
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    {if blok_2_afbeelding}
                        {blok_2_afbeelding}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_2_kop}
                        {blok_2_kop}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_2_tekst}
                        {blok_2_tekst}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_2_link}
                        {blok_2_link}
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                 {/2_blokken_met_tekst_en_achtergrondafbeelding}

                 {3_blokken_gecentreerd}
                    <div>
                    {if blok_1_afbeelding}
                        {blok_1_afbeelding}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_1_kop}
                        {blok_1_kop}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_1_tekst}
                        {blok_1_tekst}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_1_link}
                        {blok_1_link}
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    {if blok_2_afbeelding}
                        {blok_2_afbeelding}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_2_kop}
                        {blok_2_kop}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_2_tekst}
                        {blok_2_tekst}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_2_link}
                        {blok_2_link}
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    {if blok_3_afbeelding}
                        {blok_3_afbeelding}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_3_kop}
                        {blok_3_kop}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_3_tekst}
                        {blok_3_tekst}
                    {/if}
                    {if blok_3_link}
                        {blok_3_link}
                    {/if}
                    </div>
                 {/3_blokken_gecentreerd}

                 {brede_afbeelding}
                    {if afbeelding}
                        {afbeelding}
                    {/if}
                 {/brede_afbeelding}

                 {nieuwsbrief_inschrijfformulier}
                    {if titel}
                        <h3>{titel}</h3>
                        Nieuwsbrief formulier hier
                    {/if}
                 {/nieuwsbrief_inschrijfformulier}
```